# Issues with Outlook rule - sent to distribution list

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, rules

I created a rule on my Microsoft Outlook 2007. The rule is simple:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
sent to "DISTRIBUTION_LIST_1"
move it to the "FOLDER_1" folder
```

This works fine when the email is sent directly to `DISTRIBUTION_LIST_1`, but when it is sent to `DISTRIBUTION_LIST_2` where `DISTRIBUTION_LIST_1` is a member of `DISTRIBUTION_LIST_2`, the rule does not move my emails to `FOLDER_1`

How do I make all emails sent to me due to my membership in `DISTRIBUTION_LIST_1` move to folder `FOLDER_1`, in a way that I do not have to to know all the distribution lists that directly or indirectly contain `DISTRIBUTION_LIST_1` as a member.

PS: The distribution lists are not local to my outlook, but available firm-wide. I presume they reside on the exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to list all distribution lists in your rules. Nested lists are not being processed.